# Sort data in column from least to greatest or alphabetically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, sorting

I want to sort a table in SQL Server 2008 by using one column and arrange the whole table through that column. Similar to the Excel function that sorts by values and expands the sort throughout the whole row.

For example table is composed as follows:

```
ID     NameID     Value1     Value2
0      10210      -1         0 
0      3201       -1         1
1      12051      -1         1
1      11210      -1         0
1      3650       -1         0
```

If I want to sort the table by using the `NameID` column how would I go about doing that? Is it only possible to use a `SELECT` query of some sort, how would I go about editing it in that view?

Same goes with a table using strings instead of just numbers, is it possible to sort from A-Z or Z-A?

Using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Your Table Name]
ORDER BY NameID
```

you can also do this

```
SELECT *
FROM [Your Table Name]
ORDER BY NameID DESC
```

Comment: Will these allow me to edit them while in this view? I thought `SELECT *` only showed them in view form.

Comment: If you need to edit them you will need to use an UPDATE statement, you can't edit them just by selecting them

Answer (score 1):

If I want to sort the table by using the NameID column how would I go about doing that?

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY NameId ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY NameId DESC
```

Is it only possible to use a SELECT query of some sort, how would I go about editing it in that view?

Yes, you need to use `SELECT` query to get the data and sort it. If you want to update it then you would use an `UPDATE` statement.

Same goes with a table using strings instead of just numbers, is it possible to sort from A-Z or Z-A?

Yes, the `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` will work on numbers or strings.